# Problem with custom resolution with Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, xorg, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu 12.10 with Nvidia 313.09 drivers installed. I can't change resolution (native for my monitor) to `1440x900`.

In Nvidia X Server Settings list of available resolutions ends on `1360x768`. Also, my monitor is recognize as CRT-01 (in `xrandr` as Uknown) because, as I assume, it is connected to PC through VGA-DVI converter because of lack of DVI input in my monitor. In X Server Setting, in advanced options, I can set up `1440x900`, but then, top and left bars are not on 100% width (top bar) and height (left bar).

Comment: I know why the launcher is small. You don't have enough icons on it. Not to sure about why the top bar's small.

Comment: @nerof61, thats wrong - the trash always sits at at the bottom, regardless how few icons there are.

Comment: @guntbert Oh, yes. Try the custom screen on the LiveCD. What does it do?

Comment: But on Live CD there wont be Nvidia Xserver Settings, so there will be no way so i can set custom resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I recommed this tutorial for problem like mine:
http://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/howto-get-nvidia-on-linux-to-use-custom-resolutions-over-dvi/
I paste it here so it may help someone someday :)